# MYSQL- Join from two tables and show distinct data of one column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables personInfo and personPayment defined below.

Table personInfo =>

```
 personId  |     personName
    1      |         personA
    2      |         personB
```

Table personPayment =>

```
   paymentId   |    personId  |     paymentPending
    1          |         1         |         500
    2          |         2         |         700
    3          |         1         |         350
```

What I want to get is join the **personName** with the last record of each personId in the **personPayment**. It means I wanted to get the result as shown below:

```
personName  |     paymentPending
personA     |         350
personB     |         700
```

The query I have written is:

```
 SELECT a.paymentPending, b.personName FROM personPayment a, personInfo b

 WHERE a.personId  = b.personId GROUP BY a.personId ORDER BY a.paymentId DESC
```

It is returning me the first pendingPayment of person. But I want to get the last pending payment of each person. How would I do that? Need Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT a.personName,b.paymentPending FROM 
    personInfo a
    inner join
    (
    SELECT a.personid, a.paymentPending from
    personPayment a
    inner join
      (
      SELECT personId, max(paymentid) as maxid 
      FROM personPayment 
      GROUP BY personId
      ) b
    on a.paymentid=b.maxid and a.personId=b.personId
    ) b
    on a.personId  = b.personId;
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you soo much. Worked like charm! :) Stay blessed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first take only the max values from the payments table, and then do the join:

```
SELECT a.paymentPending, b.personName FROM 
(select personId, max(paymentPending) as paymentPending 
  from personPayment group by personId) as a, 
personInfo b
 WHERE a.personId  = b.personId ;
```

Comment: I tried your query. But it is not giving me the last inserted payment associated with the personId.

Comment: @kamranbhatti585 - for some reason I thought you meant highest. If you want last, just put in the `max` `paymentId` and not `paymentPending`

Comment: It's ok. Let me check it, i will get back to you.